# Can't import anything in Python3.7 after Windows 10 Update

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, out-of-memory

I'm now facing this problem. I thought it was my software problem but I could not find the bug. Then I opened a console and tried:

```
>>> import requests

Traceback (most recent call last): ...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 148, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 174, in _get_module_lock
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 60, in __init__
RuntimeError: can't allocate lock
```

I tried to import other stuff as well, and I got:

```
>>> import keyboard
Traceback (most recent call last):
"C:\Users\Lincoln\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 8, in <module>    
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc    
MemoryError
```

Pip seems not working as well:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
"C:\Users\Lincoln\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
    from http import cookiejar as cookielib
MemoryError
```

I'm really confused. They worked fine before.

Using: Python3.7, pip 18.0, Windows 10.

Tried: Restart my computer, reinstall python 
and run python as administrator but they didn't work.

I've just installed a Windows Update (KB4464218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was caused by Windows 10 Exploit Protection.

I went to **Windows Defender -> App & Browser Control -> Exploit Protection -> Program Settings** and added a custom rule (by path) and turn off all protections for python.

**It's not recommanded because it will increase the risk of your computer being attacked but it did work on my computer.**

I will be happy to accept better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstall Python

2) Lookup for "Python" in folders on your PC

3) Delete all finded folder with name "Python"

4) Install again Python

If not helped, repeat 1-3 and install Python 3.6.